# Message Queue: Can we trigger events when a message enters the queue?

Tags: php, message-queue, activemq-classic, eai

At work we're discussing whether or not to implement a message queue for our PHP application. Currently we're looking at Apache's ActiveMQ. One thing we're not entirely clear on is whether or not it's possible to trigger a process based on a message arriving in a queue.

The literature we've found so far seems to indicate that messages queues are a pull-based mechanism: the process runs regularly (either as a daemon or a cron), and pulls its incoming messages from the queue. Is it possible to turn this into a push mechanism? That is, is there a way to have the Message Queue actually initiate an HTTP request (or a process) when a message arrives? One option we have found is the Publish/Subscribe model, but this requires running our PHP app in an infinite loop to maintain an open (TCP) connection to the ActiveMQ instance, which feels like a bit of a kludge.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious solution is to let the publisher initiate the HTTP request right after storing the message, but this begs the question, why then are you using a message queue?

Having a set of consumers listening on a queue and doing their job as messages come is not a kludge, it is good, scalable design. (Though I agree that running a PHP process in an infinite loop has its cons.)

Why have you chosen a message queue as opposed to, say, a database which stores the messages? The "producer" could store the message as a row in a table and then trigger the "consumer" with the message's PK.

Comment: Good question, aib! The reason we're considering MQ is because the application is moving more towards a flexible workflow, where the business logic dictates what the next step in the process is. It seems a natural fit to use the "bins" paradigm supported by message queues.

Comment: The listening consumers is not the part I considered a kludge, that sounds like very sound architecture.. it's the while(1) { $client->fetch(); } construct that's undesirable.

Comment: I see. My personal opinion is that you should reconsider running PHP consumer daemons. I don't see much of a point in using an MQ if every message is going to trigger a consumer (what happens when 1,000,000 messages arrive simulatenously?) - you could just as well call (or just start) the consumer code from the producer in that case.

Comment: @kander: Then you need a blocking fetch() function. Fortunately, being able to block on a TCP socket is one of the few multithready/IPC-y things PHP *can* do.

Comment: In fact, I bet there'll be times when you need a blocking fetch() and times when you need a non-blocking fetchIfAvailable() function.

Comment: aib - thanks for your input! Your point regarding PHP is exactly why we're considering this whole infrastructure; we'd like to be able to run the daemon'ish parts of the application using a language more suited to that task (we're considering .Net). Good to hear that the points we're disagreeing about here are exactly the things you highlight as problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a Camel route that pulls messages from the queue (JMS component) and forwards to an HTTP endpoint (HTTP component).  You may even decide to host the Camel route on the ActiveMQ broker process -- creating a sort of intelligent routing broker. ActiveMQ makes this easy by bundling the Camel Core libraries in the ActiveMQ distribution.

Here is a recent relevant / related post:

[HTTP Post From ActiveMQ using Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353700/http-post-from-activemq-using-camel)

Answer (score 1):

Your design concept of an app to monitor the queue is the industry way of triggering an external application to run. 
Have a look at IBM Websphere "Trigger Monitor Applications". In their implementation you can have multiple trigger monitors to start apps that process messages in a queue, so it scales very well as the trigger monitor runs on the server the apps are installed on (and if you design for scalability to you should be able to have several app servers if needed).